# Building a house in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I recently bought Skyrim for my Switch. It came with Hearthfire installed and I was excited to build a house.

I chose Falkreath for my location; I knew I had to do some sidequests before the Jarl lets me buy land. I already completed one quest, which is to bring the Black-briar mead to the Jarl.

I looked up the second quest, and it is to kill the Bandit leader.

I keep on talking with the Jarl and his his steward. But I'm not getting any extra dialogue to unlock that quest.

Comment: UESP is a useful website.  Switch version is a port of the PC version so everything applies.

Answer (score 3):

In order to be able to unlock the quest, you need level 22 or higher. Then talk to the jarl and he will grant you the option to complete the quest.